# JQuery to PHP with JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

The JQuery gets the data and send it to the PHP like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var email = encodeURIComponent($('#email').val());   
        var act = encodeURIComponent($('#act').val());   
        $('#loadingB').fadeIn(); 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', url: 'activate.php',  dataType: "json",  data: { email: email, act: act,  }, 
            success: function(result) {                 
                if (!result.success) { timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#loadingB').fadeOut(); }, 1500); $('#fail').fadeIn(); }  
                else { timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#loadingB').fadeOut(); }, 1500); $('#success').fadeIn(); } 
            }  
        }); 
        return false; 
    });
```

The PHP does this:

```
$email = htmlspecialchars(trim(urldecode($_POST['email']))); 
$act = htmlspecialchars(trim(urldecode($_POST['act'])));
$first = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET active = '1' WHERE active_code = '$act' AND email = '$email' ");
$second = mysql_query("UPDATE member_search SET active = '1' WHERE email = '$email' ");

if(is_bool($first) == true && is_bool($second) == true)
{
$response = array(success => true); 
echo json_encode($response); 
}
else
{
$response = array(success => false); 
echo json_encode($response); 
}
```

the "loadingB" div fades in but never fades out to return successful or failure. I believe this is a PHP error. I don't think I'm correctly obtaining if the mysql-query returned true or false.

I know the proper data is being collect by the JQuery because I even echoed it just to make sure, the PHP is just not doing anything with it.

Comment: Did you try console.log(result.success).... what do you see...?

Comment: What's the purpose of the timeout. Why not just `$('#loadingB').fadeOut();` ? ... which is common to both conditionals, by the way, and can be taken out as a common factor.

Comment: Also, AJAX requests can be analysed in the console if there are PHP errors. Check the Network tab, find the activate.php Path, and click it. You'll be brought to a page as if the request was a basic GET with all PHP errors shown.

Comment: You've also got an extra comma in your ajax config in the data part.

Comment: I have ones of them fancy loading animated gif images lol. I just timed it out for a second so you can see it. I know that's rediculous but it makes me happy.

Comment: @Alex. OMG I did not notice that... well it works now that i took that out ahaha. I feel dumb!

Comment: Ah, well make sure to read my comment about is_bool to make sure it will actually check if the queries were successful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

```
if(is_bool($first) == true && is_bool($second) == true)
```

is equivlent but longer than:

```
if(is_bool($first) && is_bool($second))
```

Second:

```
$response = array(success => false);
//and
$response = array(success => false);
```

Should probably be:

```
$response = array("success" => false);
//and
$response = array("success" => false);
```

Thirdly (and finally) I think your logic may be off, are you sure you want to send success = true if both are **booleans** and not both being true?

Comment: @3nigma Thanks, was trying to edit it and noticed you fixed it for me lol

Comment: well I just need a way to send to the JQuery that both querys were successfull so it will prompt the user it was so thats why if both querys are true it should tell that to the JQuery via JSON and then the JQuery tells the user so. But if one or both of them return false, it tells the user that it failed. i just thought this was the way to go about it, unless you have a better way, I'm open to try anything. I'll try these updates now. THANK YOU! t

Comment: is_bool just checks if they are a true or false value, you want to check if they are true.

Answer (score 2):

one thing you can try is to change this

```
 $response = array(success => true);
```

to

```
$response = array("success" => true);
```

I would also use this

```
$first = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET active = '1' WHERE active_code = '$act' AND email = '$email' ");
$first_affected_rows = mysql_affected_rows();
$second = mysql_query("UPDATE member_search SET active = '1' WHERE email = '$email' ");
$second_affected_rows = mysql_affected_rows();

if($first_affected_rows > 0 && $second_affected_rows > 0)
{
 $response = array("success" => true); 
 echo json_encode($response); 
}
else 
{
 $response = array("success" => false); 
 echo json_encode($response);  
}
```

Depending on what you want to achieve above can be changed to suit your logic

Comment: Thank you! I like this logic!

Comment: This will work even better than checking if they are both true.

Comment: I'm using this instead now. Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: Anything for a better world. Cheers!